# Occasional rsync error code 12 "Connection reset by peer (104)" from cron task that runs every 20 minutes

Tags: configuration, rsync

I have a script run by cron that rsync's various folders to a server in a different city to publish files to websites. In case it matters, the source server is within the corporate firewall and the destination server is outside.

The script uses a locking system to prevent multiple instances of itself running at the same time.

rsync is occasionally (up to 1-3 times per day) failing with the error:

```
rsync: read error: Connection reset by peer (104) rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(604) [sender=2.6.9]
```

I found some advice suggesting that I specify a timeout value, so I added the flag --timeout=10 to the command. The result was a different error:

```
io timeout after 10 seconds -- exiting
rsync error: timeout in data send/receive (code 30) at io.c(165) [sender=2.6.9]
```

The receiving server likely has quite a heavy load, so that may be a factor.

Does anyone have any suggestions for avoiding these errors?

Comment: That's not related to rsync, it's related to your network configuration. To diagnose this, you'll need to know how all the firewalls between the two hosts are configured. `--timeout` didn't help because it fixes the symptom but not the cause: once the firewall has dropped the connection, `--timeout` makes rsync detect it faster, that's all.

Comment: I have seen similar issues on servers with very high I/O load.

Comment: http://blog.iangreenleaf.com/2009/03/rsync-and-retrying-until-we-get-it.html?m=1 discusses a workaround, the site has some formatting issues (at least the mobile view) but you can grasp the idea from the comments.

Comment: I see this error when pause receiving rsync with KILL -TSTP